# What does Yelena mean by "Enough"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow, black-widow-2021

In *Black Widow* (2021), Natasha encounters Black Widow committing suicide:

> Yelena: Do you believe me now?
>
> Natasha: How many others?
>
> Yelena: **Enough**.

What does Yelena mean by "Enough"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

She's answering the question, in a way. Natasha asked how many others are in the same condition as the suicidal woman. The answer is "Enough" - short for "Enough that we need to do something about it" with the implication that since even one more is enough to require action, the question was foolish.

Comment: I would say that the implication is not necessarily that one is enough, but that there are too many.